# How to parse html using AgilityHtmlPack

Tags: c#, html

I am having problems trying to parse the mega millions html using Agility HTML Pack. I keep getting an error instance Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' heres the web link https://www.usamega.com/mega-millions/results
heres the source I,m trying to parse

```
<td><section class="results"><a href="/mega-millions/drawing/2023/7/14">Fri, July, 14, 
2023</a><ul><li>10</li><li>24</li><li>48</li><li>51</li><li>66</li><li 
class="bonus">15</li>
<li class="multiplier">2x</li>
</ul></section></td>
<td><a href="/mega-millions/jackpot/2023/7/14">$560 Million</a></td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to get the numbers for that drawing here is the code I'm using.

```
        String PBUrl = "https://www.usamega.com/mega-millions/results";
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

        var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = Webget.Load(PBUrl);

        List<int> PbNumbersList = new List<int>();
        List<int> PowerBallList = new List<int>();

        //gets numbers from web
        foreach (HtmlNode node in 
        doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='results']"))
        {
            PbNumbersList.Add(Convert.ToInt16(node.InnerText.Trim()));
        }

        //gets powerball from web
        foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='bonus']"))
        {
            //number 1-69
            PowerBallList.Add(Convert.ToInt16(node.InnerText.Trim()));
        }
}
```

I know the text leads you believe its a powerball but I am reusing the code that worked on powerball just changed the class to match. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Ironically after hours of trouble sh0oting I found the error was caused by the node being null. I also found an eror in intellisense that the html was too complicated to parse. I found a way to generare the node tag open the html right click and select inspect find the node you want to parse right click select copy and select copy xpath paste the xpath heres a sample //*[@id="content"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1] make sure you put the backslashes sample with  2 back slashes vs seems to add them but if not they are needed  //*[@id=\"content\"]

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] had to find a different webpage see comment above. I'm posting my solution here for anyone else who wants to parse the mega millions lottery to get the past draws. This code will get up to the last 55 draws as seen on the website I added a numeric up/down to allow for the number of draws needed. the result is 2 lists the first is the main numbers for each draw. The format is
n1- n2- n3- n4 - n5
removed all whitespaces so when I split each one there wont be any additional whitespaces. Here is what I did.

```
 List<string> drawNumbers = new List<string>();
 List<string> megaBalls = new List<string>();

 private void LoadLastDraws(int DrawNumber)
    {
        var html = @"https://www.texaslottery.com/export/sites/lottery/Games/Mega_Millions/Winning_Numbers/";

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);

        //get draws based on numeric up down selection DrawNumber max = 55
        for (int i = 1; i < DrawNumber; i++)
        {
            //gets the 5 numbers in every draw format = (#-#-#-#-#) after removing whitespaces
            string nodetag = "//*[@id=\"content\"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[2]";
            var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(nodetag);
            drawNumbers.Add(RemoveWhitespace(node.InnerText));

            //Megaball list
            string MBnodetag = "//*[@id=\"content\"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[3]";
            var MBnode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(MBnodetag);
            megaBalls.Add(MBnode.InnerText);
        }
    }

    private string RemoveWhitespace(string input)
    {
        return new string(input.ToCharArray()
            .Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            .ToArray());
    }
```